# Fatal error: Call to a member function escape() on a non-object in

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to update my queries, but I stumble upon the same error again and again...

`Fatal error: Call to a member function escape() on a non-object in ...`

This is my function:

```
    //update activity
    public function updateActivity($db, $id) {
    $sql    = "UPDATE tblLeidingAgenda SET
    datum       = '".$db->escape($this->datum)."',
    uur         = '".$db->escape($this->uur)."',
    titel       = '".$db->escape($this->titel)."',
    uitleg      = '".$db->escape($this->uitleg)."',
    link        = '".$db->escape($this->link)."',
    aanwezig    = '".$db->escape($this->aanwezig)."',
    auteur      = '".$db->escape($this->auteur)."'
    WHERE id    = '".$id."'";
    return $db->insert($sql);
}
```

And this is my code:

```
if (empty($_POST['up_datum']) || empty($_POST['up_uur']) || empty($_POST['up_titel']) || empty($_POST['up_uitleg'])) {
        $error = 'no input';
    } else {
        $datecorrect=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['up_datum']));

        $agenda = new Leidingsactiviteit();
        $agenda->datum          = $datecorrect;
        $agenda->uur            = $_POST['up_uur'];
        $agenda->titel          = $_POST['up_titel'];
        $agenda->uitleg         = $_POST['up_uitleg'];
        $agenda->auteur         = $_SESSION['user']['naam'];

        if ($agenda->updateActivity($_DB,$_POST['id'])) {
            $feedback = 'ok';
            $bericht = 'test';
            mail('me@gmail.com', 'Update: '.$agenda->titel, $bericht);
        } 
        else {
            $feedback = 'not ok';
         }
    }
```

**EDIT**  `$_DB` declared...

```
 define('MYSQL_HOST',  '***');
 define('MYSQL_DB',    '***');
 define('MYSQL_USER',  '***');
 define('MYSQL_PASSW', '**');

 // Initialize (global vars) 
 $_DB = new DBConnection(MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_DB, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSW);
```

Comment: Well, `$_DB` is not an object. Why, is not clear from the code you show. The problem is happening earlier in the code

Comment: Can I make it an object? I got more than one function, all look-a-likes, and they work just fine...

Comment: Well it needs to be your database object in order to escape and update the activity.

Comment: Where is the $_DB instantiate in your code

Comment: is DBConnection extends a mysqli class? or PDO? or you created one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where is the variable `$_DB` declared?  From what you have posted, it never gets declared so I don't know what is inside the object (if it is even an object by that point to begin with).

Try `var_dump($_DB);` before the `if ($agenda->updateActivity($_DB,$_POST['id']))` and post the results of that if you don't figure out your problem.

Comment: The `var_dump` gives a NULL, so the `$_DB` is indeed empty. It's strange, cause other functions work just fine...

Comment: Please post where `$_DB = ...`

Comment: @Michiel let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2920/discussion-between-afuzzyllama-and-michiel)